# ERR-7620 Could not determine workspace for application ()

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I tried to upload file using the oracle apex brower file item and got the below error:
ERR-7620 Could not determine workspace for application ().

Environment :

- Oracle cloud
- Database : ATP Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
- Oracle Apex : 19.2

Everything use to work, i change nothing.

Thanks.